# Test ike2 vpn connection on console possible?

Tags: vpn, ikev2

Whatever I google for I find tutorials how to setup an IKEv2 VPN server either UI client configuration for different OS.

Is it possible to test the connection with a client in a Linux console environment (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)?

To connect, the following assets are available:

- public ip address
- username and password
- private shared key (PSK)

So far I've tried [vpnc](https://github.com/ndpgroup/vpnc) but get an ambiguous error message:

```
$ vpnc <IP>
$ vpnc: response was invalid [1]:  (ISAKMP_N_INVALID_EXCHANGE_TYPE)(7)
```

Comment: I receive the same error but believe vpnc to be a good client to use because I am on CentOS and it's from RHEL. Did you figure out the problem? What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

We can't make a VPN connection with the little asset info you provided. You can also try [strongswan](https://strongswan.org/) to create ipsec vpn tunnel.
To install strongswan in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install strongswan
```

There are many ikev2 test setup configurations you can find [here](https://strongswan.org/testresults.html).

You can try [rw-eap-mschapv2-id-rsa](https://strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/rw-eap-mschapv2-id-rsa/index.html). See the carol configurations [Assuming the gateway is using pubkey authentication, you need to copy the gateway CA certificate into your /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts location].

After updating the config files you can run the following commands from the terminal to let the configs take effect:

```
$sudo ipsec rereadsecrets
$sudo ipsec reload
$sudo ipsec restart
```

To connect to newly created home vpn connection, run the below command:

```
$sudo ipsec up home
```

To see the status of connection, run the below command:

```
$sudo ipsec statusall
```

To disconnect the home vpn connection, run:

```
$sudo ipsec down home
```